# Can't open camera using C++ OpenCV on android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to move a very simple OpenCV application to android. The code  tries to access the camera from a C++ .so library that is linked with the main app which is using C# and Xamarin which I doubt has anything to do with my issue. My C++ code simply tries to access the camera using cv::VideoCapture like so:

```
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0); //default camera

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        LOGE("No camera detected on this system\n");
    }
```

This however always fails despite me specifying permission in AndroidManifest.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.XamarinARapp">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <application android:label="XamarinARapp.Android">
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
</manifest>
```

Has anyone been successful accessing the android camera with cv::VideoCapture in C++? Does Xamarin have anything to do with it?

Comment: What Android API version are you testing on? i.e. Have you requested runtime camera permission in your code for API level 23+ devices?

Comment: I'm testing on on android 8.0 Nexus 5X but the app is being built for android 4.4

Comment: I see a min. target API listed in your manifest.... What about the target?

Answer (score 2):

> but the app is being built for android 4.4

Your manifest SDK versions should look like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Otherwise without the `targetSdkVersion` set and running on a API 23+ device you will need to request runtime camera permissions.

Comment: I modified my code to request run-time camera permissions using the Xamarin Plugin.Permissions, and the permissions are definitely being granted, however the issue persists. Changed both minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 24